# Can't create Service based database!

Tags: c#

I recently started learning C# and how to work in Microsoft Visual C# 2008 Express and encountered some problems and hence can't proceed with learning C# further...The problem occurs when i try to create Service-based Database!It used to pop up window with following message

> "The Event log file is full"

but now it display

> "This version is not supported!Only
>   servers up to Microsoft SQL server
>   2005 are supported!"

Creating such database is essential because the book i use requires it and i have to follow and i did exactly what the author asked...I am using exactly the same program and server,but still experience this problem.

Hope you can help me on this!

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you running?

Comment: Where / when are you seeing this message?

Comment: When i want to create Server based database...You know,Solution Explorer/Add/New Item/Server based database

Comment: Sorry,meant to say Service based,not Server based

Answer (score 1):

You've answered your own question.  You have Sql 2008 installed and the error message says anything greater than Sql 2005 is not supported.

Comment: Hmm...why would author then tell me to use it...He said that both 2005 and 2008 editions can go with visual 2008!

besides that,i installed 2005 edition before,but as soon as instal finished,my computer started crashing down as soon as Windows raised up..I had to restore the system to the previous point!
NOTE:i downloaded and installed server from Microsoft.com

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a faulty installation. Try uninstalling EVERYTHING regarding SQL and reinstalling it.

Comment: lets wait for Marc...perhaps i need to get new service pack!

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using SQL Server Express 2008 and C# Express 2008 - and it works fine. Have you installed the service packs?

Comment: what was the last one...I installed sp1

Comment: Sorry for delay; I was on the train; yes, I'm using C# Express 2008 with SP1 (3.5SP1).

Comment: Hmm,i will delete everything and start again...Can you provide me with the links you used to download everything you need?

Comment: I use the ISO at the bottom of the download page here: http://www.microsoft.com/express/download/ - but before you start deleting, try it on a VM?

Comment: VM?

Sorry,but i am not familiar with the term,xD

Comment: Virtual Machine - i.e. a fake PC in the memory of your *real* machine - very useful for testing installs. But then - if you aren't familiar with it... tricky.

Comment: Oh,oke..i'll just delete everything and download both Visual C#,SQL server and library from the link you provided

Comment: Well,i reinstalled everything and tried to create database again and now i get "The Event log file is full" message...Now to fix this and i ca finally proceed with C#

NOTE:i didn't install via ISO!

Comment: Cleared the event logs(found the solution on the site)...Hope it will be ok now!